# Audinate AVIO USB Dante audio interface not detected by Alsa

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm trying to install a Audinate AVIO USB Dante audio interface on a hedaless Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS. I'm not able to detect it properly by ALSA and Pulseaudio.

The device is a one stereo channel in and one stereo channel out.

The devices are seen by the kernel:

```
user@host:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [Module         ]: USB-Audio - Dante USB I/O Module
                      Audinate Dante USB I/O Module at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, full speed
 1 [Codec          ]: USB-Audio - USB Audio Codec
                      USB Audio Codec at usb-0000:00:14.0-3.2, full speed


user@host:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0557:2419 ATEN International Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0557:7000 ATEN International Co., Ltd Hub
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 03f0:134a HP, Inc Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 03f0:304a HP, Inc Slim Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 21d1:0001
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04d9:1702 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard LKS02
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 21d1:001b Audinate Dante USB I/O Module
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 21d1:000b
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 21d1:000a  KVM-via-IP Extender
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 3018:0101 Audinate Dante USB I/O Module
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And ALSA:

```
user@host:~$ sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Module [Dante USB I/O Module], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Codec [USB Audio Codec], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

But there is something wrong when i list it from PulseAudio:

```
user@host:~$ pactl list short sinks
0       auto_null       module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 48000Hz       SUSPENDED
```

I was expecting something like in there:

```
alsa_output.usb-Audinate_Dante_USB_I_O_Module-00.iec958-stereo
```

....that I need to configure my aplication.

I've noticed that in the PA modules list there are no alsa modules listed.

```
user@host:~$ pactl list short
0       module-device-restore
1       module-stream-restore
2       module-card-restore
3       module-augment-properties
4       module-switch-on-port-available
5       module-switch-on-connect
6       module-udev-detect
7       module-native-protocol-unix
8       module-default-device-restore
9       module-always-sink
10      module-null-sink        sink_name=auto_null sink_properties='device.description="Dummy Output"'
11      module-intended-roles
12      module-suspend-on-idle
13      module-console-kit
14      module-systemd-login
15      module-position-event-sounds
16      module-role-cork
17      module-snap-policy
18      module-filter-heuristics
19      module-filter-apply
21      module-cli-protocol-unix
0       auto_null       module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 48000Hz       SUSPENDED
0       auto_null.monitor       module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 48000Hz       SUSPENDED
0       module-systemd-login.c  (null)
1       module-systemd-login.c  (null)
38      protocol-native.c       pactl
```

Anyone who could please try to assist in this rather urgent matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make this work in the end. My software (Sienna ND Processing Engine) supports multiple driver softwars on Ubuntu, and I decided to specify access to Alsa directly and skip the configuration of PulseAudio that I was struggling with.

Next was to find the right device ID for the software to address. In my case the ID was `plughw:CARD=Module,DEV=0`

....and in my specific sw the syntax can not contain comma, so it ended up beeing entered as:

plughw:CARD=Module!*comma*!DEV=0